# website and app using the common Firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

is it possible to have an application(IOS), and a website(specifically a website for the app), use the same firebase database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As long as both apps either have the same data structure or ensure that their data structure in the tree don't conflict, they can use the same database.

Comment: Thank you so much!